# Child Theme CSS not being applied

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming, child-theming

I have a Child theme for twentytwelve I am using. It has been checked to be CSS level 3 valid free of errors.

```
/* Minimum width of 600 pixels. */
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.site {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    max-width: 68.571428571rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In the child theme I'm actively using, even though the original is imported, I placed the following

```
/* Minimum width of 600 pixels. */
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
/*BEGIN MY RESET*/

/*Site background overall*/
.site {
max-width: 100% !important;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

However only the former seems to take effect and the latter doesn't seem to be applying from the child theme i'm using.

Anyone please advise?

My child theme css: view-source:http://stanleyss.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelvechild/style.css

My parent theme css: http://stanleyss.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css

Answer (score 0):

i think you mess with child style sheet inclusion, check what function you use for include child style sheet in yous functions.php file.
if you use

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'your-style-handler', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```

then change this code with

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'your-style-handler', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```

get_template_directory_uri() use for parent theme file inclusion and get_stylesheet_directory_uri() use for child theme file inclusion.

Comment: thanks @nahid-hasan twentytwelve was updated and untouched, in the functions.php 
I have


    `// Loads our main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );`

any other ideas?